# Connecting firebird database with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, firebird, firebird2.5

I want to connect my rails 3 application to firebird database. I have followed

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firebird2.5

and

http://mapopa.blogspot.in/2009/02/rails-on-firebird-status-after-adapter.html

links. Also, I have included gem 'activerecord-fb-adapter' and gem 'fb' to gemfile.

But, I am getting the response **"No Firebird connections established."**

Also running rake db:create results in

```
 {:adapter=>"fb",
  :database=>"localhost/3050:/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/rubyonfire.fdb",
  :username=>"SYSDBA",
  :password=>"*******",
  :host=>"localhost",
  :downcase_names=>true}

 {:adapter=>"fb",
  :database=>"localhost/3050:/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/rubyonfire_test.fdb",
  :username=>"SYSDBA",
  :password=>"*******",
  :host=>"localhost",
  :downcase_names=>true}
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you connect to it from the linux command line?

Comment: @Guillem - Yes very smoothly.

Comment: I might be wrong but, why are you putting "localhost/3050:" in front of the database directory? You are already telling him the database is in localhost in the Host property. Try setting database to "/var/lib/firebird/2.5/data/rubyonfire.fdb"

Comment: @Guillem - I am not putting that, It's the result after running the rake db:create command.

Comment: BTW, I got the solution and posted it here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding **create: true** in database.yml resolved the issue. See below link for details :-

https://github.com/rowland/activerecord-fb-adapter/issues/1#issuecomment-6608210

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest to accept the answer so other people can see the answer helped you. Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq for more info on Stackoverflow.